# Find each variable before comma

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I am working with a QMK layout in emacs and would like to `query-replace-regexp` each variable before and including the comma with `XXXXXXX,`.

I have:

```
MO(RST), KC_1,    KC_2,    KC_3,    KC_4,    KC_5,                      KC_6,    KC_7,    KC_8,    KC_9,    KC_0,    RESET, \
```

and would like to end up with:

```
XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX,    XXXXXXX,    XXXXXXX,    XXXXXXX,    XXXXXXX,                      XXXXXXX,    XXXXXXX,    XXXXXXX,    XXXXXXX,    XXXXXXX,    XXXXXXX, \
```

I have tried entering `.+,` but that highlights everything up to the last comma.

I want to stop at each comma, ignoring white space. Meaning first `MO(RST),`, then `KC_1,`, etc.. Including the comma in the match is not a necessity.

As a bonus it would be nice to replace the whitespace within a 7-char
width to end up with the following spacing:

```
XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX,                   XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX, \
```

Comment: 1) Because the replacement is to be made *before* the comma that will result in two commas in a row after replacement. Is that what you want? 2) Is the replacement string always the same 8-character string `'XXXXXXX,'` or, for example, is `'KC_1,'` to become `'XXXX,,'`, where the number of `'X'`'s is to be equal the length of the string `'KC_1'`? 3) If the replacement string is always 8 characters will that be long enough to cover all words that may appear in the string?

Comment: Good catch, either will work. What I initially envisioned was up to and including the comma. Will edit the post.

Comment: ...After editing you state, "Including the comma in the match is not a necessity.". That suggests to me that in the resulting string a word can be followed by one or two commas, though I expect you want just one. You did not address my other two questions, although "either will work" may be a response to my second question. When you give an example it's always helpful to show the desired result. Had you done that my first two questions would have been answered.

Comment: Good suggestion. Updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71013768/4682839), but I can't mark it as the solution since it doesn't work in emacs. What I've been doing instead is:

```regex
Find: [A-Z_].......
Replace: XXXXXXX,
```

Find, starting at an alphanumeric character, or `_`, 8 characters total
and replace those 8 characters with `XXXXXXX,`.

`_` as in `_______` which uses the keycode from the layer below. 8
characters total: start to comma inclusive, or if the keycode is less
than 7 characters, the whitespace after to maintain alignment.

This satisfies the bonus condition.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    \S+,
Replace: XXXXXXX,
```

### Demo

Comment: Oddly, this works perfectly in your demo, but in emacs it will only highlight the last character and the comma (i.e. the first two matches are: `),`, `1,`).